# US patent 8,625,805 reinvents encrypted mail

Tags: novelty, post-grant-review, encrypted-mail, secure-messaging, us8625805

I believe US patent 8,625,805, granted to Wickr on January 7, 2014, is
either not novel, or an obvious variation of ordinary encrypted mail
as it has been used for decades.  Here is claim 1:

1. A system, comprising: a processor configured to: request a public
   key and a device identifier of at least one recipient from a first
   server; encrypt a message containing one or more components using a
   symmetric key; encrypt the symmetric key with a public key received in
   response to the request; encapsulate the encrypted message, the
   encrypted symmetric key, and the device identifier in a digital
   security bubble encapsulation; and transmit the digital security
   bubble encapsulation to a second server; and a memory coupled to the
   processor and configured to provide the processor with instructions.

The "digital security bubble" is a fanciful name for the well known
concept of a "digital envelope".  See, for example, IETF RFC 5652,
Cryptographic Message Syntax, Section 6.  The only thing unusual in
the claim is the use of a device identifier instead of a user
identifier.  However nothing prevents ordinary encrypted mail from
being addressed to a device instead of a user, in which case the
certificate of the recipient comprises a public key and a device
identifier.  In all likelihood ordinary encrypted mail was addressed
to devices before the patent application was filed, in which case what
is claimed is not novel.  But even if that were not the case,
addressing a message to a device instead of a user would be a trivial
variation on the prior art.

What could be done to challenge this patent?  I've looked at the Post
Grant Review process, but it's extraordinarily complex and expensive.

**Update**: Following the advice in the answer given by Phoenix88, I studied the patent in detail, and I filed a submission of prior art under 37 CFR 1.501 and 35 USC 301.  As I was studying the patent, I realized that there were other issues besides prior art; in particular, claim 16 illustrates a problem specific to security claims that I don't think has been discussed before.  Also, after being told by George White in his comment that US 8,625,805 was a Track I case, I also filed a response to the current USPTO call for comments on crowdsourcing of prior art pointing out loopholes that prevent third party scrutiny of applications.  I have written a [blog post](http://pomcor.com/2014/04/21/patent-illustrates-five-different-problems-with-software-patents/) about all this, since it would be off-topic to discuss it here.

Comment: If you look it up in Public PAIR it shows this was a Track I case. Track I is pay more to go faster. This case will move the average pendency down quite a bit. From Track I approval to Notice of Allowance was **three weeks**. The whole thing took 6 months from filing to issue!

Comment: Which means that there was no pre-grant publication and hence it was IMPOSSIBLE for third parties to submit prior art to the examiner, is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Francisco, another option to consider is a prior art submission to the USPTO under 37 CFR 1.501 and 35 USC 301.  See ==> http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2205.html

This creates a written record of the applicability of the particular patent(s) and/or printed publication(s) submitted.  If the patent owner attempts to assert this patent against a third party, the third party may be able to leverage your submission as part of an invalidity defense and/or as part of its own Post Grant Review filing.